# Randomly importing from a text document

Tags: c#, .net, file

I have a problem in c#. I dont know how to randomly choose a word from a txt file and save it at textBox1.Text.  Here's the code i have:

```
//When a button is clicked
        textBox1.Text = "Hi";
        string wd1 = textBox1.Text;
        string wd2 = textBox2.Text;

        if (wd1 == wd2)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("1");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("0");
        }
```

I also have a text file

```
something1=something2
something3=something4
```

What i'm trying to do exactly is take a random word from the file, project it at textbox1 and then check if the text at textbox2 is equal with the other word from the same line as the random word.

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on? Do you know how to open the file? What have you tried on the file side of things?

Comment: I don't know how to read a word randomly from a text doc, i know how to open a file and i have tried a couple of things, i originally made is so it splits the lines and reads all the words separately at once but that doesn't help because i want a randomly chosen word.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get structure of your text file, but I think this still could help you. Keep in mind that if you have really really large txt file you may hit performance issues, specially in UI-based app.

```
var path = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\test.txt";
var text = File.ReadAllText(path);

// You can use "," or Environment.NewLine or whatever as a delimeter
var words = text.Split(" ");

// Guid will get "random" seed everytime
var random = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());

var randomIndex = random.Next(0, words.Length - 1);
var randomWord = words[randomIndex];

textBox1.Text = randomWord;
```

### test.txt structure:

```
This is my test document with the test words
```

---

Comment: "Guid will get "random" seed everytime" - no, not strictly. Instead it should be "Guid will get "unique" seed everytime".

Comment: Also, `random.Next(0, words.Length - 1)` will always miss the last word in the list. The second parameter is an **exclusive upper-bound**.